# Combinatorial Interpretation of an Extension of Gaussian Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, co.combinatorics, finite-fields, q-analogs

It is well-known that the Gaussian polynomial (or Gaussian coefficient, q-binomial coefficient) $\binom{n}{k}_q$ counts the number of $k$-dimensional subspaces of an $n$-dimensional vector space over $GF(q)$.

A generalization of $\binom{n}{k}_q$ are the so-called $p,q$-binomial coefficients,

$\binom{n}{k}_{p,q}=\frac{{[n]}!}{[k]![n-k]!}$,

where $[n]=\frac{p^n-q^n}{p-q}$ and $[n]!=[n][n-1]\cdots[2][1]$.

The $p,q$-binomials equal the $q$-binomials when $q=1$.

Question 1: Is there a vector space combinatorial interpretation for the $p,q$-binomials? If there is, how does the underlying two-parameter field look like? (There is a combinatorial interpretation in terms of tableaux and lattice paths but I'm more interested with the subspace interpretation.)

Question 2 (somewhat related): A number of mathematicians have talked about the so-called $q$-disease (the widespread (at least those among working in $q$-series) interest in extending classical results to $q$-analogues.) Is  there a $p,q$-disease?

PS I'm supposed to write $[n]_{p,q}$ but it doesn't seem to work with \frac.

Comment: btw, you may wish to add the "q-analogs" tag.

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried the British spelling (analogue) but there weren't such a tag.

Comment: The variable $p$ is just making these polynomials homogeneous in an obvious way, so I would not be hopeful about a similar interpretation in a more general context. The "right" reason Gaussian polynomials count subspaces is the cell decomposition of the Grassmannian, and from that point of view the lack of homogeneity is crucial. 

Comment: Regarding question 1, keep in mind that every finite field has order $p^n$ for some prime $p$ and that there is a unique such finite field, up to isomorphism, for each such $p^n$.  

Comment: There might be a way to extend the concept of a finite field, although I'm not sure if it is profitable to do so. Had there been previous efforts to this direction?

Comment: Amplifying part of Vladimir Dostenko's comment:  These $p,q$-binomial coefficients are just what you get from the ordinary $q$-binomial coefficients if you replace $q$ by $q/p$ and then multiply by appropriate powers of $p$.  So I doubt that there will be any serious combinatorics here that isn't already in the $q$-binomial coefficients.

Comment: I apologize for misspelling "Dotsenko" in my previouis comment.